# Qiskit - expand and/or merge registers

Tags: programming, qiskit

Suppose one of my functions create some ancillary qubits and reset them. 
Then, another function wants to create a larger number of ancillary qubits. So, I'd like to reuse the first set of qubits and add the difference two them. Is there any efficient way to achieve the goal?

```
def function1(qc):
    r = 3
    ancillas = QuantumRegister(r, 'ancillas')
    qc.add(sum_q)
    # use the ancillas
    return ancillas

def function2(qc, partial_ancillas):
    r = 5
    diff = r - len(partial_ancillas)
    if diff > 0:
        # something like ancillas = partial_ancillas.add(diff)
        # or maybe ancillas = partial_ancillas + QuantumRegister(diff)
    else:
        ancillas = partial_ancillas
    return ancillas

qc = QuantumCircuit()
anc = function1(qc)
anc = function2(qc, anc)
```

Comment: There are ways to do this, as the answer explains, but they aren't so elegant. Since people, like you, want to be able to do this in a clean way, this functionality is in development and will be released soon.'

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add qubits in a QuantumRegister already set.
If your goal however is to create another ancilla registers that cannot exceed a limit of qubits, what you can do is :

```
def create_ancillas(r=3):

    ancillas = QuantumRegister(r, 'ancillas')
    return ancillas

def create_ancillas_limited(partial_ancillas,r=5):

    diff = r - partial_ancillas.size
    if diff > 0:
        return QuantumRegister(diff, 'ancillas_2')
    else:
        return None

qc = QuantumCircuit()
anc1 = create_ancillas()
qc.add(anc1)

anc2 = create_ancillas_limited(anc1)
qc.add(anc2)
```

Maybe better if you want to limit the number of qubits in your circuits when adding ancillas is :

```
def add_ancillas_limited(qc,n_ancillas_to_add=3,limit=5):
    if qc.width() - n_ancillas_to_add > limit:
        print("Cannot exceed limit!")
    else:
        qc.add(QuantumRegister(n_ancillas_to_add))
```

Comment: More or less, this is the workaround I've been using so far. However, I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @tigerjack89 What is cleaner for you ?

Comment: A built-in function or an officially proposed pattern.

Comment: I was on a rush before, but the problem with your (and mine approach) is that I can't use it for general purpose functions without complicating the code too much. For example, consider the case in which I'd like to implement a multi-control CNOT function. If I have a single QuantumRegister it's quite easy. However, if I have a bunch of them, things get messy. I was hoping for a way to create a (pseudo) QuantumRegister containing other registers inside it, but maybe the best solution is to it myself. What do you think?